# Pass parameter to constructor with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a factory as below,

```
public final class Application {

    private static IFoo foo;

    public static IFoo getFoo(String bar)
    {
        // i need to inject bar to the constructor of Foo
        // obvious i have to do something, not sure what
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
        logger = injector.getInstance(Foo.class);
        return logger;              
    }

}
```

This is the Foo definition:

```
class Foo
{
   Foo(String bar)
   {

   }

}
```

OK. I m not sure how I can pass this parameter to Foo constructor with Guice?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

All the "Guice Constructor Parameter" answers seem to be incomplete in some way.
Here is a complete solution, including usage and a visual:

[image]

```
interface FooInterface {
    String getFooName();
}
```

// Annotate the constructor and assisted parameters on the implementation class

```
class Foo implements FooInterface {
    String bar;

    @Inject
    Foo(@Assisted String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    // return the final name
    public String getFooName() {
        return this.bar;
    }

}
```

// Create a factory interface with a create() method that takes only the assisted parameters.

// FooFactory interface doesn't have an explicit implementation class (Guice Magic)

```
interface FooFactory {
    Foo create(String bar);
}
```

// Bind that factory to a provider created by AssistedInject

```
class BinderModule implements Module {

    public void configure(Binder binder) {
        binder.install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                .implement(FooInterface.class, Foo.class)
                .build(FooFactory.class));
    }
}
```

// Now use it:

```
class FooAction {
    @Inject private FooFactory fooFactory;

    public String doFoo() {
        // Send bar details through the Factory, not the "injector"
        Foo f = fooFactory.create("This foo is named bar. How lovely!");
        return f.getFooName(); // "This foo is named bar. How lovely!"
    }
}
```

Lots of helps here: https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html

Comment: Does not work for me. I have *NullPointerException* because *Foo* constructor never called. Probably you need to use your *Module* somewhere?

Comment: Please fix the missing return type of "create" method (FooFactory interface). 
It must be: Foo create(String bar);

Answer (score 11):

What you are probably looking for is to use a Guice factory.  Particularly easy with the [`AssistedInject`](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject) functionality, but they have a [manual example at the top of the page](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject). The short of it for the manual example is that you get the factory under non-static `getFoo` method that you pass whatever parameters to that you need and build the object from there.

This won't work directly if you have method interception in `Foo`, but it will work in many other cases.

To use `AssistedInject`, which to me has somewhat cleaner semantics and means less manual wiring, you'll need the [guice-assistedinject](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.inject.extensions%7Cguice-assistedinject%7C3.0%7Cjar) extension in the classpath, then when creating `Foo` (well, `FooImpl`, we should be using interfaces):

```
@Inject
public FooImpl(@Assisted String bar)
{
    this.baz = bar;
}
```

Then you create a `FooFactory` interface:

```
public interface FooFactory {
    public Foo create(String bar);
}
```

Then in your guice module:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(Foo.class, FooImpl.class)
    .build(FooFactory.class));
```

You can check out the [javadoc for `FactoryModuleBuilder`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html) for examples with more complex factories.

Comment: yeah, it sucks, it s so convoluted, structuremap is much more flexible than guice.

Comment: Where can I download the StructureMap for Java?

Answer (score 10):

I know that this is old thread but I just hit the issue myself today. 
I only need two or maximum three different instances of 'Foo' and I really didn't want to write all the bolierplate code of Factory. 
With a little googling I found this [Stubbisms – Tony’s Weblog](https://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/google-guice-injecting-primitives-in-constructors/) I would suggest this solution which is perfect if you know exactly what instances you need.

In Guice module:

```
    bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("firstFoo")).toProvider(new Provider<Foo>() {
        @Override
        public Foo get() {
            return new FooImpl("topic A");
        }
    });
    bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("secondFoo")).toProvider(new Provider<Foo>() {
        @Override
        public Foo get() {
            return new FooImpl("topic B");
        }
    });
```

Or in java 8:

```
    bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("firstFoo")).toProvider(() -> new FooImpl("first"));
    bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("secondFoo")).toProvider(() -> new FooImpl("second"));
```

And in constructor of your service where you need Foo instances:

```
@Inject
public MyService (
    @Named("firstFoo") Foo firstFoo,
    @Named("secondFoo") Foo secondFoo) {
}
```

And Foo in my case:

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

    private String name;

    public FooImpl(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

If this class is a factory, it should be a Guice-managed object, having a non static getFoo method, and the getFoo method would just use

```
new Foo(bar)
```

Not every class needs to be instantiated by Guice.

Also see [AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject), to avoid creating this factory yourself and let Guice create one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't a direct answer to what you're asking, hope it helps. I was trying to understand where the constructor parameters are being passed earlier. If they are custom classes, they should be bind-ed in the module.

```
Class CustomHandler {

  private Config config;

  @Inject
  CustomHandler(Config config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  public void handle() {
    // handle using config here
  }
}
```

Binding:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {
  bind(Handler.class).to(CustomHandler.class);
  bind(Config.class).to(CustomConfig.class);
}
```

Injection:

```
CustomHandler handler = injector.getInstance(CustomHandler.class);
handler.handle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we ended up doing. It's a bad solution that should only be used when you aren't given time and just want to live to see another day.

1. Remove all constructors, making the class default-constructible.
2. Add a public method called `init` or such which takes dependencies as parameters and assigns them to fields.
3. Use Guice's `Injector.getInstance()` to do the class discovery and construction for you, then call the `init` method with the fields you actually need.

Some forgiveness for doing this may be received by doing some aggressive null-checking that informs oblivious callers of the need to call `init` by throwing an appropriately formed `IllegalStateException`.