# Injecting Constructor Parameter value using Google Guice

Tags: parameter-passing, guice, inject

I have a simple requirement -

This is the service where I want to inject the object of `CalledService`.

```
public class CallingService {

    private CalledService service;

    @Inject
    public CallingService(CalledService svc) {
        service = svc;
    }
}
```

The `CalledService` looks like this -

```
public class CalledService {

    private String variable_value;

    public CalledService(String parameter) {
        variable_value = parameter;
    }

}
```

And let's say in the `psvm`, I am writing this code for execution -

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector());        
CallingService service = injector.getInstance(CallingService.class);
```

The issue is if `CalledService` had a non-parameterised constructor then it would have worked fine. But since it is a parameterised I don’t know how I can inject the parameter value.

Also, several other services might want to inject the `CalledService` with different parameter values. So I don't want to bind any static value to the parameter.

Can anyone suggest the simplest way this can be achieved using Google Guice? Also, I found a lot of answers in this forum but they were not exactly what I was looking for, and some solutions were overly complicated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237996/pass-parameter-to-constructor-with-guice, the link explains use of assisted inject

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestion in the comment above - [assisted inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237996/pass-parameter-to-constructor-with-guice)
You can bind instances in Guice. Please see [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InstanceBindings) for details/examples

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @Luigi, and @vsbehere for helping me out. I went through the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237996/pass-parameter-to-constructor-with-guice) link which you guys shared before also.

The answer that was mentioned there seemed a bit complicated to me, I wished the way to Inject parameters using Google Guice had been a little simpler. One thing which I was very resistant to use was the factory class and I wanted to know if its usage can be avoided. Then I went through this [documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) and I made sense to me.

Just to summarize, the purpose of the `FactoryInterface` is to help Guice build the objects. `AssistedInject` maps the `create()` method's parameters to the corresponding `@Assisted` parameters in the implementation class's constructor, in this example the implementation class is the `CalledService`. The `create()` method in the Factory Interface takes only the assisted parameters and, one should make sure they are in the same order as in the constructor.

I hope the above paragraph made sense, which explains why a Factor class is required. And this is how I solved the above-mentioned problem -

The `CalledService` now looks like this, there is a `@Assisted` keyword now in the parameter -

```
public class CalledService {

    private String variable_value;

    @Inject
    public CalledService(@Assisted String parameter) {
        variable_value = parameter;
    }

    public void printValue() {
        System.out.println(variable_value);
    }
}
```

The CalledServiceFactory is a new addition, whose purpose is to create objects of CalledService. And this is how it looks -

```
public interface CalledServiceFactory {

    CalledService create(String var);
}
```

The `CallingService` now looks like this, we are injecting a `CalledServiceFactory` instance to this class now and this will help in creating the instance of `CalledService` -

```
public class CallingService {

    @Inject
    private CalledServiceFactory factory;

    public void callingMethod() {
        CalledService service = factory.create("someValue");
        service.printValue();
    }
}
```

Inside the Module, I have configured the `CalledServiceFactory` -

```
public class AppInjector extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                 .build(CalledServiceFactory.class));
    }
}
```

And finally, for executing it, this is how I have executed it in the main function -

```
private static void main() {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector());
        CallingService service = injector.getInstance(CallingService.class);
        service.callingMethod();
}
```

This is how I have implemented it, and this is the max simplest I could trim it down to. If anyone has any optimum solution then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you took a wrong turn. Look at provides-methods instead (also, use interface binding to unleash Guice' full potential!):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Provides;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CallingService callingService = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(CallingService.class).to(DefaultCallingService.class);
                bind(CalledService.class).to(DefaultCalledService.class);
            }

            @Provides
            String provideParameter() {
                return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null);
            }

        }).getInstance(CallingService.class);

        callingService.requestStuffExecution();
    }
}
```

Interface 1:

```
public interface CallingService {

    void requestStuffExecution();
}
```

Interface 2:

```
public interface CalledService {

    void doStuff();
}
```

Default Impl1:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class DefaultCallingService implements CallingService {

    private DefaultCalledService service;

    @Inject
    public DefaultCallingService(DefaultCalledService svc) {
        service = svc;
    }

    @Override
    public void requestStuffExecution() {
        service.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Default Impl2:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class DefaultCalledService implements CalledService {

    private String parameter;

    @Inject
    public DefaultCalledService(String par) {
        this.parameter = par;
    }

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Oh boy, always so much stuff to do! Performing: " + parameter);
    }
}
```

Prints: "Oh boy, always so much stuff to do! Performing:  <The Input String>".